# In react i have raised CORS policy error so how can i handle it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

**INDEX.JS**

```
import express from "express";
import { APP_PORT } from "./config";
import db from "./database";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import Routes from "./routes";
const app = express();

app.use("/", Routes);
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.listen(APP_PORT, () => {
  console.log("app connected successfully");
});
```

**Routes.js**

```
import express from "express";
const router = express.Router();
import { postController } from "../controller";
router.get("/", postController.testing);
router.post("/create", postController.createPost);
export default router;
```

**POSTCONTROLLER.JS**

```
import express from "express";

const postController = {
  testing(req, res) {
    res.send("connected from router postcontroller");
  },
  createPost(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
  },
};
export default postController;
```

THIS ALL FILE WILL BE OF BACKEND NOW I AM USING AXIOS PACKAGE IN REACT NOW I CAN SHOW YOU FONTEND FILE

**API.JSX**

```
import axios from "axios";

const url = "http://localhost:9000";

export const createPost = async (post) => {
  try {
    return await axios.post(`${url}/create`, post);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error while calling api API", error);
  }
};
```

**createView.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Box,
  FormControl,
  InputBase,
  TextareaAutosize,
  Button,
  makeStyles,
  IconButton,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { AddCircle } from "@material-ui/icons";
import { createPost } from "../../services/api";
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  container: {
    padding: "0 80px",
    [theme.breakpoints.down("md")]: {
      padding: "0 17px",
    },
  },
  image: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "60vh",
    objectFit: "cover",
    backgroundImage: "url('https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900')",
    minHeight: "500px",
    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
    backgroundPosition: "center",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundSize: "cover",
  },
  form: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginTop: "10px",
  },
  textfield: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: "0 30px",
    fontSize: 25,
  },
  textarea: {
    width: "100%",
    border: "none",
    marginTop: 50,
    fontSize: 18,
    "&:focus": {
      border: "none",
      outline: "none",
    },
  },
}));

const initialValue = {
  title: "",
  description: "",
  image: "",
  username: "codeintelli",
  categories: "All",
  createDate: new Date(),
};

const CreateView = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [post, setPost] = React.useState(initialValue);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    setPost({ ...post, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
  const savePost = async() => {
    await createPost(post);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Box className={classes.image}></Box>
      <Box className={classes.container}>
        <FormControl className={classes.form}>
          <IconButton>
            <AddCircle fontSize="large" color="primary" />
          </IconButton>
          <InputBase
            placeholder="Enter your title here"
            className={classes.textfield}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
            name="title"
          />
          <Button
            onClick={() => savePost()}
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
          >
            Publish
          </Button>
        </FormControl>
        <TextareaAutosize
          rowsMin={5}
          placeholder="Tell Your Story"
          className={classes.textarea}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
          name="description"
        ></TextareaAutosize>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};

export default CreateView;
```

and from all of this code, i got CORS POLICY ERROR

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9000/create' from origin 'http://localhost:6464' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dBRm.png)

Answer (score 1):

The order is wrong when enabling CORS for the request.

#### index.js

```js
import express from "express";
import { APP_PORT } from "./config";
import db from "./database";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import Routes from "./routes";
const app = express();

app.use(cors()); // put this line before app.use("/", Routes)
app.use("/", Routes);
app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.listen(APP_PORT, () => {
  console.log("app connected successfully");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in the client side -> in the `package.json` add this line:

```
"proxy":"http://127.0.0.1:9000"
```

and for your requests you no longer need to include the base url in React side of the app

in API.JSX do this:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const createPost = async (post) => {
  try {
    return await axios.post(`/create`, post);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error while calling api API", error);
  }
};
```